# MVC 5 MultiSelectList Selected Values Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ListBox in a View displaying the possible choices.  However, the user's role(s) are not shown as selected.  In my UserViewModel the Roles collection contains the complete list of roles, and AspNetRoles collection contains only the roles to which the user belongs. I've tried multiple examples/variations but nothing ever shows as selected. I'm stuck.

ViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AspNetRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        UserViewModel user = new UserViewModel();
        AspNetUser aspNetUser = new AspNetUser();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            aspNetUser = db.AspNetUsers.Find(id);
            user.Id = aspNetUser.Id;
            user.Email = aspNetUser.Email;
            user.AspNetRoles = aspNetUser.AspNetRoles;

            var roles = (from r in db.AspNetRoles
                        select r).ToList();
            user.Roles = roles;
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.ListBox("AspNetRoles",
    new MultiSelectList(Model.Roles, "Id", "Name", 
    Model.AspNetRoles.Select(m => m.Id)))
```

Comment: My ViewModel has ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles

Comment: I guessed that was the case and have added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not posted your model, but it appears that property `AspNetRoles` is a collection of a complex object (you cannot bind to a complex object, only a value type - or in the case of ListBox, a collection of value type). You can handle this by changing `AspNetRoles` to `int[]` (assuming the `ID` property of `Role` is `int`)

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AspNetRoles, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Id", "Name"))
```

Note, Its always better to use the strongly typed helpers.

Comment: Thanks! I tried changing AspNetRoles to int[] and I'm able to get the selected values in the ListBox.