# MVC Model binding returns Id list instead of object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Working on an MVC web project using an Entity Framework back end.

One of my EF objects is called "Staff". There is a separate object called "Team" and these exist in a many-to-many relationship, mediated by a "TeamMember" table.

If you create entries across these tables in the DB, a "Staff" member ends up with "TeamMember" objects for each "Team" they belong to.

In the edit screen for Staff, I've chosen to mediate this via a multi-select list. However, when the form posts back to the browser I'm getting a comma-separated list of TeamID values here, rather than actual objects. Obviously, I've screwed up the model binding somewhere.

Here's how I'm creating the relevant form element:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeamMembers, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.TeamMembers, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.TeamList, "TeamId", "Name", Model.TeamMembers))
    </div>
</div>
```

The ViewBag is being populated like this:

```
ViewBag.TeamList = db.Teams.ToList();
```

The EF objects relate to each other with these properties:

```
// on Staff
public virtual ICollection<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }

// on TeamMember
public int StaffId { get; set; }
public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }

// on Team
public virtual ICollection<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You havent screwed up the model binding, selecting from your `MultiSelect` will return an array of the selected values.

Comment: @Ric Model.IsValid is false because it's got string values where it's expecting objects. Are you saying the only way to handle this is to give them a different name and process them into objects before saving?

Comment: this is similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058033/mvc-5-multiselectlist-selected-values-not-working - this is where using a `ViewModel` comes in handy rather than modifiying your data / business object

Comment: @Ric ah, right. So using a POCO or some other intermediate object? I'd rather not jump that hoop for this one instance if possible.

Comment: you could always just add a property to your object and ensure it is not mapped to your database! something like `public int[] TeamMembers {get;set;}` and use that in the `ListBox`

Comment: @Ric D'oh! Of course. If you'd be kind enough to edit your answer with that suggestion, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind to complex models using the `ListBoxFor` method - you must bind to some type of array - say `string[]` or `int[]` in order to get the selected values.

As mentioned, this is where using a `ViewModel` object comes into use - modifiying your data object isn't really what you want to do, but using an object specifically for the purposes of displaying your values on the UI.

See example usage here:

[mvc-5-multiselectlist-selected-values-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058033/mvc-5-multiselectlist-selected-values-not-working)

As requested, if you don't want to use VM's for your scenario, just add the following property ensuring it does not get mapped back to your DB:

`public int[] SelectedTeamMembers { get; set; }`

And use the following:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTeamMembers, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.TeamList, "TeamId", "Name", Model.TeamMembers))
```